# Validation error in test but error array is empty

Tags: validation, testing, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this code for creating a topic and post in a forum application in Rails 3.1:

```
def create
  @topic = Topic.new(:name => params[:topic][:name], :last_post_at => Time.now)
  @topic.forum_id = params[:topic][:forum_id]
  @topic.user = current_user

  if @topic.save
    @post = Post.new(:content => params[:post][:content])
    @post.topic = @topic
    @post.user = current_user

    @post.save!
    ...
```

When posting to the `create` method via the corresponding form, the topic and the post are created and both `save` calls are successful.

When I call the `create` method via a functional test, the topic is saved but the post has validation errors.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: 
app/controllers/topics_controller.rb:23:in `create'
test/functional/topics_controller_test.rb:26:in `block in <class:TopicsControllerTest>'
```

The test looks like this:

```
test "should create topic" do
  post :create, :topic => {:name => "New topic", :forum_id => forums(:one).id}, :post => {:content => "Post content"}
end
```

(`current_user` is logged in via a setup method.)

When I display the errors of the post object via the debugger or with `@post.errors.full_messages`, the error array is empty.

The `Post` model looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And the `Topic` model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :last_poster, class_name: 'User'

  attr_accessible :name, :last_poster_id, :last_post_at

  belongs_to :forum
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

How can I find out what is causing the validation error?

Comment: could you post the actual error message? Also, do you have validations on the Post model you can put up?

Comment: Whats your topic model look like?

Comment: That's the complete Post model? No validations at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used mocha's `Post.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(false)` in a test that was executed before my failing test.

Apparently, you have to restore the original behavior before proceeding with other tests by calling `Post.any_instance.unstub(:valid?)`.